# how to highlight part of textarea html code

Tags: javascript, python, regex, highlight, regexbuddy

I want to achieve a python version web regexbuddy,and i encounter a problem,how to highlight match values in different color(switch between yellow and blue) in a textarea,there has a demo what exactly i want on http://regexpal.com,but i was a newbie on js,i didn't understand his code meaning.
any advice is appreciated

[image]

Comment: Added Tag : javascript , this looks to be a question on how to highlight a text area using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `pre` element over the textarea. So when you type anything it is copying the input on the `pre` element, applying some filters.

For example:

```
<pre id="view"></pre>
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
```

When you type on `#code` it is copying the value, applying filters and adding the HTML to the `#view`.

```
var code = document.getElementById("code");
var pre = document.getElementById("pre");
(code).onkeyup = function (){
    val = this.value;
    val = YourRegex(val);
    (pre).innerHTML = val;
};
```

`YourRegex` would be a method to match the `regex` and return some parsed content to the `pre`, allowing you to customize the appearance of the `textarea` (that is actually an element over it).

```
function YourRegex(val)
{
    // This function add colors, bold, whatever you want.
    if (/bbcc/i.test("bbcc"))
        return "<b>" + val + "</b>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To save time you should consider using an existing library for this requirement.

Quote from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/):

> As textarea elements can’t render HTML, this plugin allows you to highlight text inside textarea elements.

[jQuery highlightTextarea](http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/).

**Demo: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/dMLBpg)**

Usage:

```
$context.highlightTextarea(options);
```

Comment: You could consider making a Stack Snippet instead of linking to Codepen. This way, you can run it directly on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Julian, you should disclose that the article was written by you.  Also, I'd like to point out that the specific plugin that you recommended is the exact same one that I pointed out back in 2013... Not a big deal, but it probably would have been more considerate to add a comment to my answer rather than downvoting my answer and adding your own...

Comment: @rinogo It is not a promotion of a project. I've just named the article since there's a description why it's not possible to use a normal highlighter library. However, I've updated my answer to not look like a promotion. About your answer: While you're providing a link to a project that would solve the issue, you don't provide an example (Codepen, JSFiddle, StackOverflow Snippet) or a usage example.

Answer (score 0):

@BrunoLM's solution is excellent, but might require more hacking than you're comfortable with.  If you're interested (and if jQuery is already in your stack), the following plugin may be worth taking a look at:

http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/

Comment: Can the downvoter please provide a reason why this is not a good answer?  For a "newbie on js" (sic), this seems like a reasonable answer.